# IIS 7.5 confused between Windows Authentication and Forms Authentication

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5

I'm seeing some strange behavior from a Server 2008 R2 box running .net 4 and IIS 7.5 in an integrated app pool.

The root web.config is pretty clear that I want to use windows authentication.

```
<authentication mode="Windows"/>
```

no surprises there.

I have a directory that I would like to secure, so I've added the following web.config to that directory:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="MYDOMAIN\MYUSER" />
            <deny users="*" />
        </authorization>
 </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Windows Authentication is enabled in IIS, and specified by the root web.config, so I expected the usual Challenge/Response dialog to pop up and ask for a password. Instead I got redirected to a non-existent URL http://mysite.com/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2ftestdir

Which seems to be the default login directory for Forms Authentication, which I'm not using so the request returns a 404 error.

ACLs on the underlying directories allow the intended user to access the file.

Anybody seen IIS behave in this manner?

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, this looks like a misunderstanding between authentication modes.

IIS 7+ has two modes - one using a built-in HTTP-level set of authentication options - 
in `<system.webServer>`, and one for ASP.Net, in `<system.web>`.

The ASP.Net behaviours don't become available until you run an ASP.Net handler - whether in Classic or Integrated mode - and then still (usually) apply after the IIS-level `system.webServer/security` settings.

In the example above, the addition of an ASP.Net page changed the behaviour for (at least) that page, and I'd *guess* possibly added wildcard handler mappings to handle extensionless URLs through .Net.

There's then also the URL Authorization (IIS, i.e. `system.webServer`) vs .Net Authorization (.Net, i.e. `system.web`) rules to consider - in general, pick one set per app and stick to it.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer on this one, but it is truly bizarre. I put up a simple .chstml page up on the site. Even though that was just a test page, it appears to have cast an evil spell on IIS somehow.

Razor syntax is really nice, but it appears dangerous to mix with a standard web forms site.

Comment: I know this is a very old post but I am getting similar behavior on a legacy site but the only difference is that <authentication mode="Forms"/> but its acting like its set to Windows. Was the removal of the .chstml page the culprit here?